# Unable to start GRUB2 on Triple boot Macbook Pro with OS X Lion, Windows 7 and Ubuntu

Tags: windows, boot-failure, macosx, dual-boot

I installed Windows 7 using Bootcamp. Then I created a partition from the empty space in the Windows partition and another 4GB partition for the linux swap using GParted. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in the the newly created partition from the Windows partition. Now GRUB2 does not load and I can only see the blinking cursor on the top right when selecting "Windows HD" from the 'option' key at the start up. OS X works fine but nothing else. Could someone please help me fix this? I am attaching the boot-info from the boot-repair tool.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1040169/

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is a good idea to install grub-efi (use a bootable install disk, mount your root-fs then run

```
chroot /mnt/{mount-point of your install}
sudo apt-get install grub-efi
```

and reboot. If grub-efi is already installed then it may be better to install the default grub and remove grub-efi (some macs work better WITHOUT the grub-efi bootloader)

Answer (score 0):

1. **Run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)**, update it, click "Advanced options", go to the
   "GRUB location" tab, tick the "Separate /efi: sda1" option, apply,
   indicate the new URL that will appear.
2. **Setup your BIOS** to make it boot on the grub*.efi file which is in your EFI partition